# Getting syntax error using WITH (Common Table Expressions) in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql 8.0.21. I am trying to execute this statement:

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT h.store_hsh, 
                Avg(s.sales)     AS SALES_AVG, 
                Avg(s.customers) AS CSTMR_AVG 
         FROM   sat_day_facts s 
                INNER JOIN link_day l 
                        ON s.link_day_hsh = l.link_day_hsh 
                INNER JOIN hub_store h 
                        ON h.store_hsh = l.store_hsh 
         GROUP  BY h.store_hsh) 
SELECT t.store_hsh, 
       Now()                               AS LOAD_DATETIME, 
       Now()                               AS LOAD_END_DATETIME, 
       t.sales_avg, 
       t.cstmr_avg, 
       (SELECT 1 + Count(*) 
        FROM   t t1 
        WHERE  t1.sales_avg > t.sales_avg) AS SALES_RANK;
```

but I keep having this error

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WITH t as  (select h.STORE_HSH, AVG(s.SALES) as SALES_AVG , AVG(s.CUSTOMERS) as'` at line 1

I checked the manual of SQL but still don't understand what is going wrong.
Does anyone could help?

Comment: Try `SELECT VERSION();` I'm guessing you are using the 8.0.21 client or Workbench 8.0.21, but you're connected to a MySQL Server that is older. It's the Server that needs to be a version that supports the `WITH` syntax.

Comment: not your immediate problem but once made readable it's apparent that this code does not have a from clause in the main  query select and would not syntax anyway

Comment: *I checked the manual of SQL but still don't understand what is going wrong.* Maybe MySQL version which the documentation is applied to and MySQL version of your server does not match?

Comment: @BillKarwin *I'm guessing you are using the 8.0.21 client* The CLI of any version will accept and send any text to the server - even deliberate nonsense.

Comment: @Akina - the OP stated they were using 8.0.21, but they're getting an error that they should not get on that version of the server. Hence Bill's guess that they're looking at a client tool's version when they're making that assertion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe. It is possible that OP mixes up server and client versions (probability - high). But maybe there is some other situation - for example the version information is taken from another server errorneously. Anycase the error message is one generated by MySQL server and tells nothing about client version itself.

Comment: @P.Salmon Not true, this query has no syntax errors on MySQL 8. I tested on my test container, and it complains that table `sat_day_facts` does not exist, which tells me it at least got through syntax parsing with no error.

Comment: @BillKarwin you were right. when I checked the version with select version () I got this result '5.0.24a-community-nt'. but how can I upgrade my version? Since according to mysql Installer I am using the version 8.0.21

Comment: I can't guess what your environment is. It's possible you have two instances of MySQL installed on the same host (using different ports). Or it's possible they are on different servers and you're looking at the wrong one.